# ApplicationUser custom object is null Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

```
 public class ApplicationUser
        : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,
            ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {

        public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

        public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

and fluent api:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.OrganisationId).IsRequired();
  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.DisplayName).HasMaxLength(100);
  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasRequired(m => m.Organisation);
```

When I find the user the Organisation object is always null:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(1);

var organisation = user.Organisation; //this is always null.
```

how can I eager load or configure the relationship by using fluent api to load the object?

Comment: Try setting `Organisation` property to virtual: `public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }`, then create `UserManager` instance with custom database context: `var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new CustomDbContext()));`

Comment: Comment above from @TetsuyaYamamoto is the correct answer. After setting my Property to Virtual, it worked!